# Check if client is online

Tags: java, client-server, jax-ws

So I have a server with a few clients.

When a client sends in a message I'd like the server to send it out to any one of the clients. However I don't really want the clients to be polling for messages, rather, I'd somehow like the server to check if they are online and then send them the message if they are.

I'm assuming the client will need a socket that's listening for incoming messages?

But what's a good method for the server to 'test' if the client is online? How the server know the address of the client?

I'm using Java with JAX-WS.

I'm sure there must be some method or design pattern for this that I'm not finding via google?

Comment: Have a look at protocols like websocket, bosh, comet, etc.

Comment: I agree, look at WebSocketd, I don't know others

Comment: At a glance Websocket looks like it'l do the trick. I'll give it a try and post it as the solution if all goes well. Cheers guys.